# Set highlight point radius in flot

Tags: flot

I am using world most beautiful plotting javascript library `FLOT.`
I want to know how can we set highlighted point radius and color if yes then how.

I am highlighting a points using

```
plot.highlight(series, dataPoint);
```

I could not find any way of doing it with current API.

I also refered [Support for colors in the highlight() function.](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/247).But fail to understand how to use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlight color can be set with the API under

```
var options = {
    series: {
        ...,
        highlightColor: 'red'
    }
};
```

There is no support for setting the radius in the API, but you could change it in the code. In `jquery.flot.js` (version 0.8.1) in the `drawPointHighlight` function in line 2983 change

```
var radius = 1.5 * pointRadius;
```

`pointRadius` is the size of the unhighlighted point and the factor `1.5` changes the size of the highlight.

Comment: Hey nice to c your post Raidri.But if not mistaking its series highlight color not for the highlighted point.

Comment: In the `drawPointHighlight` function in the code you can see that it uses `series.highlightColor`.

Comment: `octx.strokeStyle = parseColor(color).scale(1, 1, 1, 0.5).toString();
+                                                                   var fillStyle = parseColor(color).scale(1, 1, 1, 0.5).toString();` is added in new diff.Please check it.Originally it was using series color then js has been modified to support custom color

Comment: I don't see that even in the 0.9 alpha version ... but if there is support for custom color then you just have to look where to set it. You could always go for modifying the code if the API doesn't support what you want like with the highlighting size.

Comment: That diff is yet to be merged.Anyways Lets triage on this.+1 for ans.Thanks